# How to register PHP application as a service in Consul

Tags: php, rest, service, consul, service-discovery

I have a small `PHP service` that provides some functionality to other services.

I have a Go service as well.

I have tried to find any example of how to register a PHP application as a service in Consul.

Is it possible to do this?

I would be grateful for any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **Consul REST API (/agent/service/register)** to register your service. This approach can be used for any type of applications, not just for PHP applications.

The following link has more info:
https://www.consul.io/api/agent/service.html#register-service

**Other approaches:**

- If you use Nomad as your scheduler, then you can have Nomad register the service to consul (See https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/service.html for more details)
- If your PHP is running as a docker container, you can possibly make use of containerpilot to handle the registration (See https://www.joyent.com/containerpilot for more info)

Thanks,
Arul